# Getting error Failed pulling the last config block: retry attempts exhausted channel on raft orderer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am trying to implement the Raft orderer to my HLF network which is implement on aws EKS cluster(Kubernetes). I have create the 3 orderer in Raft orderer and 2 orgs which have 2 peer each which is running fine however when I trying to create the channel its give error from orderer side. as `" [orderer.common.cluster.puller] func1 -> WARN 15fce Received error of type 'failed to create new connection: connection error: desc = "transport: error while dialing: dial tcp: lookup orderer2.dfarmadmin.com on 10.100.0.10:53: no such host"' from {orderer2.dfarmadmin.com:7050 "` and `" [orderer.consensus.etcdraft] confirmSuspicion -> ERRO 225cb Failed pulling the last config block: retry attempts exhausted channel=testchainid node=3"`

I am  confused how to solve it as all file and other stuff in right folder. Please see the attached screenshot of error[image: orderer issue]

Please let me know what I am doing wrong also if need more information let me know.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: This is a DNS issue ... your orderer container/pod cannot resolve the `orderer2.dfarmadmin.com` address.

Comment: Hi Gari, could you please help me how to resolve the DNS issue??

Comment: Do you have a DNS entry for `dfarmadmin.com`?

Comment: sorry I am very new to k8s and docker, How to know the DNS entry for dfarmadmin.com?

Comment: I guess I'll start with where does `dfarmadmin.com` come from?  Did you just make it up?